# Как поменять цвет эллипса на желтый?

Tags: svg, svg-animation

Почему не работает команда анимации `<animateColor>`?

```html
<svg id="svg1" viewBox="0 0 520 520" width="500" style='border: 1px solid black'>
<ellipse cx="100" cy="50"  rx="80" ry="40" fill="red">
<animateColor attributeName="fill" 
         from="red" to="yellow" dur="3s"
         repeatCount="indefinite"/>
</ellipse>
</svg>
```

Comment: Ну и где вопрос?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/animateColor)

> Этот элемент `<animateColor>` - устарел в SVG 1.1 Second Edition и может быть удален в
> будущей версии SVG. Он не предоставляет функций, которые еще не
> доступны с помощью элемента `<animate>`. Поэтому авторам следует
> использовать элемент `<animate>`.

Заменяем `<animateColor>` на `<animate>` и всё работает

```html
<svg id="svg1" viewBox="0 0 520 520" width="500" style='border: 1px solid black'>
<ellipse cx="100" cy="50"  rx="80" ry="40" fill="red">
<animate attributeName="fill" 
         from="red" to="yellow" dur="3s"
         repeatCount="indefinite"/>
</ellipse>
</svg>
```